# TimeDelta class in ActionScript?

Tags: actionscript-3

Is there any ActionScript class which represents "durations of time", similar to the TimeDelta class in Python?

**Edit**: Thanks for the responses. I should clarify a bit, though: I want be able to ask questions like "how many weeks are between date0 and date1" or "let `x` represent "one day".  What is `date2 + x`?"

I know I can do all this by representing dates as timestamps... But I'm hoping to find something nicer.

Comment: Someone has also suggested I try using the Tween class... I'll look into that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted a full AS3 port of the .NET TimeSpan class on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/169201/actionscript-3-0-calculate-timespan-between-two-dates/457213#457213), which sounds exactly like what you need.

```
// 5 days from new
var ts : TimeSpan = TimeSpan.fromDays(5);
var now : Date = new Date();
var fiveDaysTime : Date = ts.add(now);

// Diff between dates
var d1 : Date = new Date(2009, 1, 1);
var d2 : Date = new Date(2009, 1, 6);
var ts : TimeSpan = TimeSpan.fromDates(d1, d2);
```

Comment: Ah, that looks like exactly it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use time() in the Date class to get unix era milliseconds and use that for time delta.

Answer (score 1):

If you subtract two dates:

```
var dateDiff = date1 - date2;
```

dateDiff will hold the number of milliseconds between the two dates. You can then convert from milliseconds to whatever useful number you like.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a class which measures change in time in Actionscript 3. According to this blog post on [Adventures in Actionscript](http://www.adventuresinactionscript.com/blog/27-07-2008/accurate-timing-with-actionscript-3), timing is very inaccurate in the Flash player on the web. That post is pretty informative and has a class called SuperTimer that might help you. You might want to keep this inaccuracy in mind if using solutions posed by Justin Niessner and toastie.

Comment: I'm not worried about timer accuracy – I'm dealing with dates ("there is a meeting at 4:00 on Monday" type of dates).  Thanks for the link, though.