# AS3: Calculate the time difference between two times?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I want to create a function which calculate the time difference between two times.
For example I am sending times as

```
     timedifference(1 AM,5 PM);
```

How could I calculate the time difference between 1PM to 5PM?
Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: read this DateUtil class :http://as3.casalib.org/docs/org_casalib_util_DateUtil.html#getTimeBetween

Comment: can you provide '`format`' of time you use?

Comment: @mgraph:i dont want time difference between two dates.

Comment: @user1113426: i am using 12 hour format.

Comment: @SwatiSingh first you should convert `1 am` to date fromat then use the class

Comment: Are you really passing the time values as string's? 1 AM, 5 PM?

Comment: I have updated my answer. Check it out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the answer I want:

```
public static function timeDifference(startTime:Date, endTime:Date) : String
{
    if (startTime == null) { return "startTime empty."; }
    if (endTime   == null) { return "endTime empty."; }
    //trace(" endTime.valueOf() "+endTime.valueOf()+" startTime.valueOf() "+startTime.valueOf())
    var aTms:* = Math.floor(endTime.valueOf() - startTime.valueOf());
    var timeTaken:* =( int(aTms/(    60*60*1000)) %24 );
    //trace(timeTaken);
    return "Time taken:  "  
        + String( int(aTms/(24*60*+60*1000))     ) + " days, "
        + String( int(aTms/(    60*60*1000)) %24 ) + " hours, "
        + String( int(aTms/(       60*1000)) %60 ) + " minutes, "
        + String( int(aTms/(        1*1000)) %60 ) + " seconds.";
}
```

Usage of this function as:

```
var myDate:Date = new Date("3/18/2012 10:00 PM");
var myDate1:Date= new Date("3/19/2012 12:00 PM");

timeDifference(myDate,myDate1);
```

Comment: Seems copy of http://stackoverflow.com/a/6990505/1216775. At least give due credit to the original answerer.

Answer (score 1):

I asume ur inputting the time at a string since you have AM and PM ... this is a bad idea if you ask me but since that's what you have ill just try to awnser on it.

You would first have to split the string, and add 12 hours if you are on PM, then do time2 - time1 for the difrence...

```
trace(timedif("1 AM", "3 PM"));

function timedif(string1:String, string2:String){
    var time1 = string1.split(" ");
    var time2 = string2.split(" ");

    var newtime1:int = time1[0];
    var newtime2:int = time2[0];

    if(time1[1] == "PM"){ newtime1 = newtime1 + 12; }
    if(time2[1] == "PM"){ newtime2 = newtime2 + 12; }

    var difrence = newtime2 - newtime1;
    return difrence;
}
```

I beleive this is the awnser to your question, i'm not saying its a good solution

Comment: what happen when i will pass timedif("12 AM", "6 PM")? it should return 18 as time difference.