# How to get time with respect to MySQL timestamp, in ActionScript 3?

Tags: php, mysql, actionscript-3, timestamp

I want to show an ActionScript 3.0 `Timer`, with respect to a timestamp gotten from MySQL.

So suppose MySQL (PHP) returns a string like `$my_birthday="2013-05-22 12:30:45"`
I got it from ActionScript by a `URLLoader`, and I want to show the timer like this:

```
My age:
01 hours 01 minutes 42 seconds
```

What function should I use in:

```
public function timerHandler(e:TimerEvent)
{
 log_textfield.text = String((new Date()).time) - my_birthday; // I need to convert the   Date().Time to unix timestamp I guess, and a function for time difference.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[This answer has a TimeSpan class that you may want to use](https://stackoverflow.com/a/457213/477878). The code below should do what you need to get the TimeSpan where you can get the parts you need to display. I don't have Flash on this computer though to test, so your mileage may vary :)

```
// new Date() is allergic to dashes, it needs slashes.
my_birthday = my_birthday.replace('-', '/');
var sinceBirthday = TimeSpan.fromDates(new Date(), new Date(my_birthday));
```